# Большой многоугольник и исчерпание памяти

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Есть следующий элементарный код на Qt:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(ui->graphicsView);

    scene->setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene::NoIndex);

    QPolygon polygon;

    for (int x = 0; x < 10 * 1000 * 1000; ++x)
    {
        polygon.append( QPoint(x, 100 + rand()%50 ) );
    }
    scene->addPolygon(polygon);

    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
}
```

Он падает со следующим сообщением:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В компьютере имеется 10 ГБ ОЗУ, программа падает в тот момент, когда исчерпала всего 800 МБ. В системе остается свободно еще 5 ГБ. Проблема связана с фрагментацией?

Я пытался создать график из тысячи полигонов меньшего размера, но результат тот же. Полигоны использую для того, чтобы не рисовать все линиями, потому что будет гораздо дольше.

Comment: У вас 32 битная сборка, 10 ГБ ОП не получится использовать

Comment: Я знаю, что у меня х32 сборка, она и не должна использовать 10 ГБ, почему она падает на 800 МБ? х32 процессу должно быть доступно не менее ~3.6 ГБ оперативной памяти.

Comment: Откуда вы взяли число 800 МБ?

Comment: @Максим Вы уверены что падает именно в приведенном вами месте, по сообщению этого не видно? Если закоментировать ваш цикл падает или нет?

Comment: @Максим Попробуйте сначала создать вектор `QVector<QPoint>`, заполнить его, а потом за раз добавить в объект. `QPolygon` так умеет.

Comment: Если приложение не пролезает по памяти, такой подход не поможет. Продолжаю утверждать, что нужен свой компонент рисования на основе `QPainter`

Comment: лучше попробовать сделать `polygon->reserve(10000000)` вначале. Но я сильно сомневаюсь, что нужно 10кк точек.  Это даже больше, чем точек на 4к дисплее.

Comment: @KoVadim автор пытается заложить возможность зума, поэтому добавляются сразу все точки. Надо делать лоды, или что-то подобное, в лоб такую задачу решать неправильно.

Comment: @Максим И кстати ваш полигон вы забываете зачищать, утекает он у вас. Лучше его на стеке создавать.

Comment: Это явление называется "фрагментация памяти".

Comment: Я использую Qt для построения графиков только по той причине, что он позволяет сделать огромный график и не париться об оптимизациях и выводе при скроллинге. По крайней мере, так написано в мане. Если стандартная сцена и вьювер требуют ручной оптимизации при выводе 10-100 млн. точек, то мне проще все написать на Win API и OpenGL

Comment: Кстати, во всех примерах, которые я нашел, сцену в Qt создают не на стеке. Может быть это неправильно, и сцену стоит создавать на стеке? Я попробовал и так, и так, память все равно течет.

Comment: @Максим я написал Вам ключевые слова для поиска, а KoVadim написал, как избежать ошибки, которую Вы наблюдаете